# What is the color reproduction accuracy on mid-2012 non-Retina Macbook Pro-s and how applicable it is for photo editing?

Tags: macintosh, color-spaces, srgb, laptop

What is the color reproduction accuracy (sRGB color space coverage) for Apple Macbook Pro non-Retina models from mid-2012 and how applicable it is for photo editing?

I read that MBP Retina display covers 99% of sRGB color space. I also heard that mid-2012 non-Retina models feature an improved sRGB gamut reproduction compared to the older models. I am yet to find the actual numbers supporting that statement.

Comment: I think that this might be better suited elsewhere, it is unlikely to be on topic here.

Comment: Updated the question with pieces relevant for this community.

Comment: I think this question is both difficult to answer and only interesting to a small number of people (since it only applies to a single laptop model, not even all recent Macbooks but only mid-2012 non-Retina Pro-s)

Comment: Can't that be said for any "review this item" questions? Discussion at http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions

Answer (score 2):

This is the most comprehensive post I have found. I would copy and paste but there are lots of pictures:

- [AnandTech: The 2011 MacBook Air (11 & 13-inch)](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4528/the-2011-macbook-air-11-13inch-review/7)

Comment: Juju, this is from 2011, but I require information for Pro models produced in 2012 :)

Comment: I don't think that the screen resolution changed much over the half a year that your stating about. This is a pretty complete guide however, but then it depends what you have in terms of anti-glare which may have an affect on colours. The screens in a macbook air and macbook pro would not really be any different. Well I am not 100% but I thought that this would help you. If you really want to know you should email apple. That is all you can do. I have a macbook pro early 2012. If apple can't tell you then they don't have the best customer help.

Comment: MacBook Pros and Airs do not necessarily have the same displays. I believe Pros are IPS and some Airs are TN.